# See configured rules even when inactive

Tags: firewall, ufw

I'm wondering if it's possible to get UFW to list the configured firewall rules even when it's not enabled. I only have ssh access to the server at this time, and I don't want to enable UFW if there's not a rule configured allowing ssh. However, since UFW is currently not enabled, I just get an "`inactive`" message when I run "`ufw status`".

Is there a special flag I can use, or even some configs file I can look at to see what rules are configured even when the firewall is disabled?

Comment: The current answer is `ufw show added` courtesy of @simon.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is currently not a way to show the rules you have entered before enabling the firewall via the CLI command. You can inspect the rules files directly however. /lib/ufw/user*.rules contain the rules controlled via the 'ufw' CLI command. Eg:

```
 $ sudo grep '^### tuple' /lib/ufw/user*.rules
```

This will show output like the following (for the rule added with 'sudo ufw allow OpenSSH):

```
 /lib/ufw/user.rules:### tuple ### allow tcp 22 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 OpenSSH - in
```

The 'tuple' is the shorthand used internally by ufw to keep track of rules, and can be interpreted as one of these:

```
 ### tuple ### <action> <proto> <dst port> <dst> <src port> <src> <direction>
 ### tuple ### <action> <proto> <dst port> <dst> <src port> <src> <dst app name> <src app name> <direction>
```

It might be useful to be able to add another status command to support this. Please consider filing a bug.

Comment: putting the files in `/lib` is pretty strange in my opinion

Comment: @pqnet maybe they agree 'cos at some point they moved it to no longer `/lib/ufw/user*.rules`  it's now `/etc/ufw/user*.rules`

Answer (score 176):

There is now a **`ufw show added`** command that will list the configured rules for you, even when the firewall is inactive. It was added as a fix for [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ufw/+bug/987784) and added in v0.33

So now you can do:

```
# ufw status
Status: inactive

# ufw allow ssh
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)

# ufw show added
Added user rules (see 'ufw status' for running firewall):
ufw allow 22

# ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup

# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The format of the output from `ufw show added` makes it much easier to write the delete command for each rule too.

Answer (score 19):

General rules are in `/etc/ufw`. User defined rules are in `/lib/ufw/user*`.

Comment: Magic - /lib/ufw/user.rules has human-readable rules in the ### RULES ### section. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

In Ubuntu 16.04, user defined rules are stored in `/etc/ufw/user.rules`. Therefore, you can see the rules with:

```
sudo cat /etc/ufw/user.rules
```

Comment: Hence, on Ubuntu 16.04 you can use this: `sudo grep '^### tuple' /etc/ufw/user*.rules` for the formatted list of user added rules.

Comment: @Ville, don't do that.  Use `sudo ufw show added` instead.

Comment: I didn't know that @ctbrown, thanks. It also seems to work when ufw is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

From the command line, there doesn't seem to be a way.  However, if you're SSH'ing from an Ubuntu box (to an Ubuntu box), you might want to try this, slightly convoluted method :

Basically, install gufw on the remote box, then connect with X forwarding and run the GUI.

On the remote device, after connecting with `-X` as an option :

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
sudo gufw
```

That will show you the ruleset without having to activate it.

Be warned that if the remote device is a true "headless" server, then installing GUFW might pull down an unpleasant number of dependencies.  But unless someone here know a trick to make UFW show you the output you need without activating it first, then this might be your only option.

I did try `sudo ufw show raw`, but that shows the iptables output, which I can't make head nor tail of.

Comment: Thanks for the tidbit about "ufw show raw" - I must have missed that in the man pages. When I run it, I don't see anything that jumps out at me as being rules, which means I may not have any configured, but I don't want to chance it just yet. And yes, installing gufw would require a very large number of dependencies to be installed so I think I'll shy away from that approach.