# How to secure phpmyadmin

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, security, phpmyadmin

OK, so I have several sites on a vps with ssl certificates. I have mod security setup as well as tripwire. My question then relates to phpmyadmin security. If my IP is 123.123.123.123 I can access phpmyadmin using 123.123.123.123/mypmyadmin-IHaveChangedThisURL.

And even though I changed the phpmyadmin url, phpmyadmin is still accessible if you can find the url.

I have added a blank html file to the root directory and so no directory index is given using the vps hostname or vps IP.

Is there anything else I can do to protect the IP use and attempts to get to phpmyadmin etc?

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things could be done. I will explain my ideas and the way how they could be implemented within Apache2.

---

#### 1. Use HTTPS connection to protect your data from sniffing

- First enable SSL module if it is not enabled: `sudo a2enmod ssl`.
- Оpen port 443 (HTTPS) into the [**firewall**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html). You should use your custom port here.
- Follow [**this manual**](https://askubuntu.com/a/900433/566421) and enable a free certificate from Let's Encrypt.
- Check [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/903375/566421) and disable Weak Ciphers.
- Then you can [**force all users to use HTTPS**](https://askubuntu.com/a/873876/566421).

---

#### 2. Change the URI of PhpMyAdmin

To change the URI, within the default configuration, you should edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` and change the first part (`/phpmyadmin`) of this directive:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Restart Apache and you will be able to access PhpMyAdmin through the new URI.

---

#### 3. Run PhpMyAdmin on different port

Here is a step-by-step manual: [How to run PhpMyAdmin on different port](https://askubuntu.com/a/897133/566421). Don't forget to open this port into the Firewall.

---

#### 4. Access PhpMyAdmin only locally through SSH tunnel

Run PhpMyAdmin on different port. Let's assume it is port `99`. **Close this port** into the Firewall. Then establish SSH connection by a command similar as:

```bsh
ssh -fTN -R 99:localhost:99 <user>@<domain>or<ip>
```

- This command will create ssh [tunnel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Local_Port_Forwarding), where the remote `-R` port `99` is forwarded to the local port `99` on the `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).
- The options `-fTN` will push the connection in to the background.

Then PhpMyAdmin should be accessible via the web browser of your local machine on the URL `http://localhost:99/`. More ideas could be find here:

- [Access remote multiple servers behind NAT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005337/access-remote-multiple-servers-behind-nat/1006245#1006245)
- [IPTables only allow localhost access](https://serverfault.com/questions/247176/iptables-only-allow-localhost-access)
- [Allow Ubuntu Server Access only from specific IP's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615343/allow-ubuntu-server-access-only-from-specific-ips)

---

#### 5. Protect PhpMyAdmin URI path via Password authentication

More details could be found in this Apache's manual: [Authentication and Authorization](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html). The package [`apache2-utils`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04) must be installed. In short the steps are:

- Create folder outside of `/var/www`, where the password file will be kept. Then generate password file. Let's assume the name of this new folder is `/var/www-auth`:

  ```bsh
  $ sudo mkdir /var/www-auth
  $ cd /var/www-auth
  $ sudo htpasswd -c .htpasswd.phpmyadmin <user>
  New Password: *********
  Re-Type New Password: *********
  Adding Password For User <user>
  ```

  - `.htpasswd.phpmyadmin` is the name of the file in which the password will be stored.
  - `user` is the login name that will be used.
  - `*********` is the password :)
  - `-c` means create new file. If this option is omitted `htpasswd` command will try to add the new `login name` to an existing `.htpasswd.file`.
- Modify PhpMyAdmin authentication type, through edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` in this way (or create `.htaccess` file):

  ```bsh
  <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
  .....
      <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
          <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
              AuthType Basic
              AuthName "The name of the authentication form - type some user and password hints"
              AuthUserFile /var/www-auth/.htpasswd.phpmyadmin
          </IfModule>
          Require valid-user
      </IfModule>
  .....
  </Directory>
  ```
- Enable the modules and restart Apache2 to apply the new configuration:

  ```bsh
  sudo a2enmod authz_core authz_user authn_file
  sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
  ```
- Now to access PhpMyAdmin's URI you must provide the login name `user` and its `password`.

---

#### 6. Protect PhpMyAdmin URI path via Two Factor Authentication (2FA):

- Follow steps **1** and **3** from [**this manual**](https://askubuntu.com/a/904035/566421) to generate `.google_authenticator` file, located in your `$HOME` directory. In step **4** is described how to generate authentication codes.
- Create a new directory under `/var/www-auth`. Let's assume the name of this new folder is `google_authenticator`:

  ```bsh
  sudo mkdir -p /var/www-auth/google_authenticator
  ```
- Copy the file `$HOME/.google_authenticator` into that directory and change its permissions (it must be readable for `www-data`):

  ```bsh
  sudo cp $HOME/.google_authenticator /var/www-auth/google_authenticator/user
  sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www-auth/google_authenticator/user
  ```

  **Please note that the file name determines the login name! The file name will be used as username while logging-in to your secure website.**
- Modify the new file by adding the directive `" PASSWORD=qwerty`, where `qwerty` is the new login password.

  ```
  E3CY3TNSNBXXXXXX
  " RESETTING_TIME_SKEW ...
  " RATE_LIMIT 3 30 ...
  " WINDOW_SIZE 17
  " DISALLOW_REUSE 48885555 ...
  " TOTP_AUTH
  " PASSWORD=qwerty
  4567...
  ```
- Install `mod_authn_google` for Apache2. Unfortunately I this module is unavailable within Ubuntu's repository, but we can get it from [this repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/csbuild:/DBA/RedHat_RHEL-7/x86_64/). The steps are: (1) go to your `Downloads`, (2) download the package [`dba-apa24-mod_authn_google-r22... .rpm`](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/csbuild:/DBA/RedHat_RHEL-7/x86_64/dba-apa24-mod_authn_google-r22-1.1.x86_64.rpm), (3) extract `mod_authn_google.so`, (4) place the file in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`, (5) grant appropriate permissions, (6) Create module load file:

  ```bsh
  cd $HOME/Downloads
  wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/csbuild:/DBA/RedHat_RHEL-7/x86_64/dba-apa24-mod_authn_google-r22-1.1.x86_64.rpm

  rpm2cpio dba-apa24-mod_authn_google-r22-1.1.x86_64.rpm | cpio -iv --to-stdout ./DBA/apache24/WWW/2.4.x/modules/mod_authn_google-r22.so > mod_authn_google.so

  sudo mv mod_authn_google.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
  sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_google.so
  sudo chmod g-w /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_google.so

  echo "LoadModule authn_google_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_google.so" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/authn_google.load

  sudo a2enmod authn_google
  ```
- Modify PhpMyAdmin authentication type, through edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` in this way (or create `.htaccess` file):

  ```bsh
  <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
  .....
      <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
          <IfModule mod_authn_google.c>
              AuthType Basic
              AuthName "The name of the authentication form - type some user and password hints"
              AuthBasicProvider "google_authenticator"
              GoogleAuthUserPath /var/www-auth/google_authenticator
              GoogleAuthCookieLife 3600
              GoogleAuthEntryWindow 2
          </IfModule>
          Require valid-user
      </IfModule>
  .....
  </Directory>
  ```
- Enable the modules and restart Apache2 to apply the new configuration:

  ```bsh
  sudo a2enmod authz_core authz_user authn_google
  sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
  ```
- Now to access PhpMyAdmin's URI you must provide the login name `user`, its `password` and 6 digit `token code`:

  [image]

---

### 7. Use ModSecurity for Apache

With ModSecurity you can add more flexible restrictions to the PhpMyAdmin's URI.
In [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/922144/566421), under the section *"ModSecurity Rules > SAS > Iptables"*, I've described in short how we can create custom rules for ModSecurity.

Comment: If extra paranoid (in this instance it would be very good) i would actually suggest a virtualhost dedicated to serving phpmyadmin to localhost only, then using ssh tunnel and browser proxy - so phpmyadmin is only available if ssh access is also achieved...

Comment: #pa4080 awesome. Thats gonna keep me busy fro a while and may require other answers but I think I get the most of that. exept maybe ssl. I have lets encrypt certificates on all of the domains and so dont know hif I can apply one using an IP? Not sure about that but I will get started on this tomorrow. Thanks again for the awesome response. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Hawk007 I'm happy to help! You cannot apply SSL/TLS certificate using an IP, but by the default configuration PhpMyAdmin must be accessible via `https://each-of-your.domains/phpmyadmin-uri`. I intentionally wrote thath option, because you had said, you using SSL, but access PhpMyAdmin through the server's IP address.

Comment: The main source of security should come from your strong password and securing data in transit via TLS. Anything else is just security through obscurity and can be easily circumvented.

Comment: @Eiver, I've reordered the options.