# 18.04.1 LTS Apache Module mod_md needs mod_watchdog

Tags: apache2

big problem (for me) is:

I was able to install `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_md.so`. It's Apache Module `mod_md`.

But it is **impossible** to get module `mod_watchdog`.
`mod_md` needs `mod_watchdog` (see [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_md.html): "Prerequisites. This module requires mod_watchdog to be loaded as well. ")

Does Ubuntu 18.04.1 supports `mod_watchdog`? It seems not.

If that's the case, where can I get sourcecode? Is it the only way? Or does there exists compiled versions of `mod_watchdog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `mod_watchdog` is a part of the package [`apache2-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/apache2-dev/filelist). So what I've tried on a virtual machine is:

```
sudo apt install apache2-dev
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-md
sudo a2enmod md
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

There wasn't provided any error message. So probably you will be able to use `mod_md` - I haven't made further tests...

---

If the above doesn't help, another alternative, that you can try is to extract this module from a package of any other Linux distribution, where it is compiled. Time ago, I was made this for `mod_authn_google.so` - review section 6 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/939241/566421).

Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic comes with Apache/2.4.29. I found `mod_watchdog-2.4.23-1...x86_64.rpm` in [this repository](https://openmandriva.pkgs.org/3.0/openmandriva-main-release-x86_64/apache-mod_watchdog-2.4.23-1-omv2015.0.x86_64.rpm.html), and probably it will be comparable with the Apache's version of Bionic. So the steps to deploy this package on your system are:

```bsh
# Install the dependencies
sudo apt install rpm2cpio

# Download the package
cd $HOME/Downloads
wget http://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/3.0/repository/x86_64/main/release//apache-mod_watchdog-2.4.23-1-omv2015.0.x86_64.rpm

# Extract the module file
rpm2cpio apache-mod_watchdog-2.4.23-1-omv2015.0.x86_64.rpm | \
cpio -iv --to-stdout ./usr/lib64/apache/mod_watchdog.so > mod_watchdog.so

# Deploy the module
sudo mv mod_watchdog.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_watchdog.so
sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_watchdog.so

# Create .load file
echo "LoadModule mod_watchdog /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_watchdog.so" | \
sudo tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_watchdog.load

# Enable the module and restart Apache2
sudo a2enmod mod_watchdog
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: Shame on me. Using command apache2 -V . I can see: compiled in modules: mod_watchdog.c . Thanks for help.

Comment: Tried both options:
option 1 fails with `libapache2-mod-md` package not found. and option 2 fails with `apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_watchdog.load: Can't locate API module structure `mod_watchdog' in file /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_watchdog.so: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_watchdog.so: undefined symbol: mod_watchdog
` error