# Port forwarding through ssh tunnel Showing Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 99

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, phpmyadmin, port-forwarding

I am trying to secure the PhpMyAdmin to revoke accessing publicly. I tried following step 4 of this link 
[Secure PhpMyAdmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938398/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin). But when I try to connect it showing a warning that unable to forward to the remote host.

I have Apache server running on that port. I tried accessing one public Linux server to another but that also didn't work. I'm trying to access mac PC. Though it shouldn't be a problem about the platform of remote PC.

I was able to forward a port that didn't have anything running. but failed to start apache2 on that port after connecting.

Comment: Only `root` can use [well known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports), or those between 0 and 1023.  I am assuming (and you should not be) `ssh`ing into the machine as `root`.  Try a much higher port, such as 8080.  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` needs to allow for Port Forwarding, as well.

Comment: @earthmeLon Post it as an answer :)

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1194105/ssh-troubleshooting-remote-port-forwarding-failed-for-listen-port-errors

Answer (score 1):

Only `root` can use [well known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports), or those between 0 and 1023. I am assuming (and you should not be) `ssh`ing into the machine as `root`. Try a much higher port, such as 8080.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` needs to allow for Port Forwarding, as well.