# ufw Does Not Block Port for curl

Tags: firewall, ufw, curl

I am trying to block outgoing traffic to port 9200 temporarily. My use case is I want to test what happens when an Elasticsearch cluster (at port 9200) becomes unreachable to my application.

I configured firewall rule `sudo ufw deny out 9200`. The response was

```
rules updated
rules updated (v6)
```

What is the correct way to block outgoing traffic sent to port 9200?

Then I tried checking whether the port really is blocked using `curl remotemachine:9200`. Curl received the normal Elasticsearch response:

```
...
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
...
```

Comment: Did you enabled the service with `ufw enable` ?

Comment: It seems to me that curl and other apps like firefox use a random local port like 59045 or something like that for outgoing connection. Thatd be hard to block?

Comment: what's the output of `sudo ufw status`?

Comment: @ob2 , no I thought it was enabled by default. Blocking of the port works as expected when I enable ufw.

Comment: @GonrasKarols , the response is "Status: inactive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your rule by following the items [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30781/see-configured-rules-even-when-inactive) which essentially is `sudo ufw show added`.

Here's a dry-run and won't change anything with a line-by-line rundown:

1. Grabs the status of `ufw`
2. Searches for `inactive` in the output, if found (or success, denoted by `&&`) do line 3
3. Enable `ufw`, but if `inactive` was not found (line 2 failed, denoted by `||`) then do lines 4 and 5
4. Show the currently added rules, send stdout to line 5
5. Search for 9200 (since that's the port we want), if that fails (`||`) do the next line
6. Add the deny outbound 9200 rule

```
sudo ufw status | 
grep inactive && 
sudo ufw --dry-run enable || 
sudo ufw show added | 
grep 9200 || 
sudo ufw --dry-run deny out 9200
```

Remove `--dry-run` and you should be sorted, like this:

```
sudo ufw status | grep inactive && sudo ufw enable || sudo ufw show added | grep 9200 || sudo ufw deny out 9200
```

There is nothing wrong with your syntax (it does block UDP and TCP - you can add proto for that but this use case doesn't matter). Your syntax is the same as:

`sudo ufw deny out to any port 9200`